# Creating a list of formID's to be included in one code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have 18 google forms I am working with. 
I have written a code that does exactly what I want it to do for the very first form.
How can I make a formID List within my code that will update all 18 google forms without copy and pasting the code 18 times and changing the form ID for each?

In the code below, X is always going to be the same spreadsheet, while Y is where I would like to have a list of multiple forms.

```
var ssID = "X";
var formID = "Y";

var wsTeamNames = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Team Names");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){

 var labels = wsTeamNames.getRange(1,2, 28,1).getValues()[0];

  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
    var options = wsTeamNames
                  .getRange(4,2,28,1)
                  .getValues()
                  .map(function(o){return o[0] })
                  .filter(function(o){ return o !== "" });
    updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options)
  });

 }

function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {

  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
   return item.getTitle();
  });

  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();

  updateDropdown(itemID,values);

}


function updateDropdown(id,values) {
  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you use for update?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FormApp.openById to update all forms, e.g.

```
function updateForms() {
  var formIds = ['id1','id2','id3'];
  formIds.map(function(formId)){
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

    /* Here comes the code to update form */
  })

}
```

For your particular case after edit, it should be like

```
var ssID = "X";
var formIDS = ['id1','id2','id3'];

var wsTeamNames = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Team Names");

formIds.map(function(formId)){
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

    main()
})
```

Comment: When I try to run this code it tells me it can not find the main function.
Is this something dealing with parenthesis somewhere maybe?

Comment: You already have main function in your code. Just put add it here